# Length of Hirzebruch continued fractions

Tags: nt.number-theory, continued-fractions, elementary-proofs

Suppose $a,b$ are two natural numbers relatively prime to $n$ and to each other. Assume $n\geq ab+1$. Suppose further that $\frac{a}{b}\equiv k \pmod{n}$ for some $k\in \lbrace 1,2,\dots, n-1\rbrace$ and $\frac{a}{b}\equiv k'\pmod{n+ab}$ for some $k'\in \lbrace 1,2,\dots, n+ab-1\rbrace$.

> **Question:** Is there an elementary proof that the length of the continued fraction of $\frac{n}{k}$ is equal to the length of the continued fraction of $\frac{n+ab}{k'}$?

This came out of a broader result, and for this particular case I can prove it using routine toric geometry, however I would like to know of some elementary tricks to deal with continued fractions.

---

Here by continued fraction I mean the Hirzebruch continued fraction 
$$\frac{n}{k}=a_0-\frac{1}{a_1-\frac{1}{a_2-\cdots}}.$$
For example, when $a=2, b=3$ and $n=17$, we get $k=12$ and $k'=16$, so the fractions are 
$$\frac{17}{12}=2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{4-\frac{1}{2}}}\qquad and \qquad\frac{23}{16}=2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{5-\frac{1}{2}}}.$$

Comment: Sometimes known as the "negative-regular continued fraction". 

Comment: Is there, by any chance, a pun on Kettenbruch?

Comment: @Alain Valette: I am not sure if you mean something more specific, but the Hirzebruch is the mathematician, as he conisdererd them somewhere, sometimes also the name Jung is mentioned in addition. So one finds say Hirzebruch-Jung-Kettenbruch in German texts. I could envision somebody coming along and calling it (or rather the plural) Hirzebrüche as a pun; I found nothing googling for this. But, the next person doing so might ;) 

Comment: Also one can replace $n+ab$ by $n+kab$ with any $k>0$

Comment: @Gjergji:  Your "*routine toric geometry*" line brought a smile to my face. I suppose you could try to convert the routine geometry facts into   statements on the geometry of numbers. As far as I can remember the length of the Hirzebruch-Jung continued fraction is related to the number of  edges  in  a Newton polygon, the convex hall of the nonzero lattice points in side the angle determined by the positive horizontal  semi-axis and the   ray of slope $a/b$.

Comment: @Liviu: The Hirzebruch-Jung continued fraction also tells you the Euler characteristic of the minimal resolution of a toric surface, which is what I was referring to. In this case, one can come up with two isomorphic surfaces, whose Euler characteristics are given by the two fractions in question.

Comment: According to Perron (Vol. 1, $\S$ 43) this fraction as known as ``reduced regular continued fraction'' (reduziert-regelmaessige Kettenbrueche).

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi Is it $k'(\bmod (n+ab))$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lets call expansions
$$\langle
x_1,\ldots,x_m\rangle:=\cfrac{1}{x_1-{\atop\ddots\,\displaystyle{-\cfrac{1}{x_m}}}}$$
(as in Perron's book) reduced regular continued fractions (RRCF).
Probably they are older then Hirzebruch.

We'll prove more precise statement.

**Theorem.** *If $(n,ab)=1$ and $n>ab$ then RRCF for all numbers
$$\left\{\frac{ab^{-1}\pmod{(n+kab)}}{n+kab}\right\}\qquad(k\ge
0)$$ are almost equal: they have equal length and differ only in
one partial quotient.*

**Remark 1.** Common factors of $a$ and $b$ can be moved into $k$.
If $d=(a,b)$, $a=da_1$, $b=db_1$, then `\begin{gather*} \left\{
\frac{ab^{-1}\pmod{(n+kab)}}{n+kab}\right\} =\left\{
\frac{a_1b_1^{-1}\pmod{(n+kab)}}{n+kab}\right\} \\=\left\{
\frac{a_1b_1^{-1}\pmod{(n+(kd^2)a_1b_1)}}{n+(kd^2)a_1b_1}\right\}.
\end{gather*}`
So we can assume that $(a,b)=1$.

**Remark 2.** The proof will be given in terms of modified
continuants $K(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ (see ``Concrete Mathematics'' for
more explanations). These polynomials are defined by initial
conditions
$$K()=1,\quad K(x_1)=x_1$$
and the following recurrence:
$$K(x_1,\ldots,
x_n)=x_nK(x_1,\ldots, x_{n-1})-K(x_1,\ldots,
x_{n-2})\qquad(n\ge2).$$ (In the usual definition minus must be
replaced by plus.) For convenience $K_{-1}:=0$ (empty RRCF is
$0$).

In terms of continuants RRCF can be written as
$$\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle=\frac{K(x_2,\ldots,
x_n)}{K(x_1,\ldots, x_n)}.$$

**Continuant's properties.** All these properties can be proved by
induction (or from ``Euler’s rule'').

1$^{\circ}.$ $K(x_1,\ldots, x_n)=K(x_n,\ldots, x_{1})$.

2$^{\circ}.$ `\begin{gather*} K(x_1,\ldots, x_n,x_{n+1}, \ldots,
x_{m+n})\\=K(x_1,\ldots, x_n)K(x_{n+1}, \ldots,
x_{m+n})-K(x_1,\ldots, x_{n-1})K(x_{n+2}, \ldots, x_{m+n})
\end{gather*}`

3$^{\circ}.$ $\begin{vmatrix}
     K(x_2,\ldots, x_{n-1})&K(x_2,\ldots, x_n) \\
     K(x_1,\ldots, x_{n-1})&K(x_1,\ldots, x_n)
\end{vmatrix}=-1$. In particular if
$$\frac{A}{a}=\left<r_1, \ldots, r_v\right>=\frac{K(r_2, \ldots,
r_v)}{K(r_1, \ldots, r_v)}$$ then
$$K(r_1, \ldots, r_{v-1})=A^{-1}\pmod{a},\qquad K(r_2, \ldots, r_{v-1})=\frac{AA^{-1}\pmod{a}-1}{a}.$$

4$^{\circ}.$ Euler's identity (see [A Short Proof of Euler's Identity
for Continuants](http://iam.khv.ru/articles/Ustinov/nth15_eng.pdf) for additional arguments). (2$^{\circ}$ and
3$^{\circ}$ are special cases of this identity) $$
K(x_1, \ldots, x_{m+n})K(x_{m+1}, \ldots, x_{m+l})-K(x_1, \ldots,
x_{m+l})K(x_{m+1}, \ldots, x_{m+n})$$ $$+K(x_1, \ldots,
x_{m-1})K(x_{m+l+2}, \ldots, x_{m+n})=0.
$$

**Proof of the Theorem.** For a given $n$ define
$a^{-1}:=a^{-1}\pmod{n}$, $b^{-1}:=b^{-1}\pmod{n}$, $0\le a,b\le n-1$
(inverse number is always least possible nonnegative) and $t_a$,
$t_b$ such that $aa^{-1}=1+t_an$, $bb^{-1}=1+t_bn$. Let $$
\frac{A}{a}=\left\{\frac{bt_a}{a}\right\}=\left<r_1, \ldots,
r_v\right>,\qquad A^{-1}:=A^{-1}\pmod{a};$$
$$\frac{B}{b}=\left\{\frac{at_b}{b}\right\}=\left<q_1, \ldots,
q_u\right>,\qquad B^{-1}:=B^{-1}\pmod{b};$$
$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\left<q_1, \ldots, q_u,x,r_v, \ldots,
r_1\right>.
$$
By 2$^{\circ}$, 3$^{\circ}$ and main recurrence $$
Q(x)=K(q_1, \ldots, q_u,x,r_v, \ldots, r_1)=$$
$$xK(q_1, \ldots, q_u)K(r_v, \ldots, r_1)-K(q_1, \ldots,
q_{u-1})K(r_v, \ldots, r_1)-K(q_1, \ldots, q_u)K(r_{v-1}, \ldots,
r_1)$$ $$=xab-aB^{-1}-bA^{-1}.
$$
Hence $$ Q(x)\equiv -bA^{-1}\equiv -b((bt_a)^{-1}\pmod{a})\equiv
-t_a^{-1}\equiv n\pmod{a},$$ $$Q(x)\equiv -aB^{-1}\equiv
-a((at_b)^{-1}\pmod{b})\equiv -t_b^{-1}\equiv n\pmod{b}.$$
Therefore
$$Q(x)\equiv n\pmod{ab},$$
and for some integer $x_0$ we have $Q(x_0)=n$. We know that $n>ab$. It
means that
$$x_0ab-aB^{-1}-bA^{-1}>ab,$$
so $x_0\ge 2$ and $\left<q_1, \ldots, q_u,x_0,r_v, \ldots,
r_1\right>$ is really RRCF. Choosing arbitrary $x=x_0+k$ we'll get
progression $n+kab$ as in the statement of the theorem.

Let's check the numerator $P(x)$. Final step $P(x)\equiv
ab^{-1}\pmod{Q(x)}$ follows from identity
$$bP(x)-BQ(x)=a,$$
which is a special case of Euler's identity. Nevertheless this
identity can be verified directly with help of
1$^{\circ}$--3$^{\circ}$: $$
P(x)=K(q_2, \ldots, q_u,x,r_v, \ldots, r_1)=$$
$$xK(q_2, \ldots, q_u)K(r_v, \ldots, r_1)-K(q_2, \ldots,
q_{u-1})K(r_v, \ldots, r_1)-K(q_2, \ldots, q_u)K(r_{v-1}, \ldots,
r_1)$$ $$=xaB-a\frac{BB^{-1}-1}{b}-BA^{-1},$$ $$
bP(x)-a=B(xab-aB^{-1}-bA^{-1})=BQ(x).
$$

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful, and definitely the kind of argument I was looking for.

Comment: Will it give anything useful for toric geometry?

Comment: This answer was published as a short note "On continued fractions of equal length" at http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=dvmg&paperid=276&option_lang=eng

Answer (score 4):

Forgive me, this should be in the comments, but I am still building my reputation up to comment. If a=5, b=4, n=7, then k=3, k'=8, and n+ab=27.

Here, $\frac{n}{k}=\frac{7}{3}=3-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2}}$ but $\frac{n+ab}{k'}=\frac{27}{8}=4-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{3-\frac{1}{2}}}$. Am I missing something or is there a further assumption on these numbers?

Comment: Yes, there was a crucial missing assumption, that $n > ab$. Thank you for pointing this out.