# What can we say about the reciprocal of a reduced regular continued fraction?

Tags: nt.number-theory, continued-fractions

For positive integers $a>b>0$, we can represent $a/b$ uniquely as $$\frac{a}{b}=a_1-\cfrac{1}{a_2-\cfrac{1}{\cdots-\cfrac{1}{a_n}}}=:[a_1,\dots,a_n]^{-}$$ with $a_i\geq 2$, and this is called the reduced regular (or Hirzebruch-Jung) continued fraction.

For ordinary continued fraction $[a_1,\dots,a_n]^+:= \frac{a}{b}=a_1+\cfrac{1}{a_2+\cfrac{1}{\cdots+\cfrac{1}{a_n}}}$, it is known that $1/[a_1,\dots,a_n]^+=[0,a_1,\dots,a_n]^+$ : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/reciprocal-of-a-continued-fraction.

Is there anything that we can say about the reciprocal $1/[a_1,\dots,a_n]^-$ of a reduced regular continued fraction $[a_1,\dots,a_n]^-$?

Also are there any books or papers about properties of reduced regular continued fractions?

Comment: Is it not simply $1/[a_1,\dotsc,a_n]^- = - [0,a_1,\dotsc,a_n]^-$?

Comment: @ZachTeitler You're right, but I am curious whether there are more interesting properties about the reciprocal

Comment: You might like to edit your question, or even just ask a new one, that focuses on that question (asking for books or papers about properties of these things).

Comment: Zagier, Zetafunktionen und quadratischer Korper

Comment: What OP calls "reduced", I call "negative". There's a link at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4003950/negative-continued-fraction-of-euler-mascheroni-constant to a paper with some discussion of these fractions. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4656843/negative-continued-fraction-with-maximal-numerator and https://people.math.osu.edu/costin.10/Seminar/OSU55min.en.pdf I proved a theorem or two in Myerson, G. On semi-regular finite continued fractions. Arch. Math 48, 420–425 (1987). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01189635

Comment: Other references: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111312/length-of-hirzebruch-continued-fractions and https://hal.science/hal-02270543/document

Comment: http://www.numbertheory.org/php/surd_pos_neg.html calculates positive and negative continued fractions for quadratic irrationals.

Comment: Any thoughts on any of the suggestions you have received, blancket?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for references!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to look at two reduced regular continued fractions (RRCF)
$$\frac{p}q=1-\cfrac{1}{a_1-\cfrac{1}{\cdots-\cfrac{1}{a_n}}}=\cfrac{1}{b_1-\cfrac{1}{\cdots-\cfrac{1}{b_m}}}$$ as on two sides of classical continued fraction (CCF).
First fraction gives upper convergents, while the second one gives lower convergents. The union of these two sets is the set of best approximations of the first kind. They are either convergents or intermediate fractions of the CCF representing given number.

They are also clearly visible from geometrical point of view. Let $L$ be a lattice with the basis $(q,0)$, $(p,1)$. We can define two sails
$$S_+=\partial\,\mathrm{Conv}\{(x,y)\in L: x,y\ge 0, (x,y)\ne 0\}$$
$$S_-=\partial\,\mathrm{Conv}\{(x,y)\in L: x\le 0,y\ge 0, (x,y)\ne 0\}.$$
The first RRCF corresponds to the integer points on the boundary of $S_+$, while the second one to the integer points on the boundary of $S_-$. Convergents of CCF correspond to the vertices of $S=S_+\cup S_-.$ Intermediate fractions are integer points on $S$ between vertices.

On the picture below the lattice $L$ has basis $(17,0)$, $(7,1)$ (and contains some unnecessary information). The boundary of the grey region is $S_-$, numbers $s_j$ and $q_j$ are continuants.

[image]

Explicit formulae for the coordinates of all these points can be written in terms of continuants, see definition [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/111713/5712).